# MVC redirect to a new action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is my controller that performed database query and return the results to the form that call this controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string File)
{
    var list = db.Objects.Where(x => x.protocol == File).ToArray();
    ViewBag.Files = list;
    //return View();
}
```

Now instead of return back the results the the same form i want to open new form so i have changed this to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string File)
{
    var list = db.Objects.Where(x => x.protocol == File).ToArray();
    ViewBag.Files = list;
    return RedirectToAction("ShowList", ???);
}
```

And create new method:

```
public ActionResult ShowList(string site)
{
    var list = db.Objects.Where(x => x.protocol == site).ToArray();
    ViewBag.Files = list;
    return View();
}
```

Currently i don't  know how to send my string that received to the new method (ShowList)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass a param to a your new action, you have to do this :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string File)
{
    var list = db.Objects.Where(x => x.protocol == File).ToArray();
    ViewBag.Files = list;
    return RedirectToAction("ShowList", new { site = "yourparam" });
}
```

By this way, you will pass the param `site` to the ShowList method.

Hope it helps !

Comment: +1. This applies if the new action is in the same controller as the original. If it's in a different controller, use `RedirectToAction("ShowList", "ControllerWhereShowListIsDefined", new { site = "yourparam" })`

Answer (score -1):

You can wirte

return RedirectToAction(ControllerName, ActionName);

For example

return RedirectToAction("[ControllerName]", "ShowList");

Comment: return RedirectToAction("YourControllerName", "ShowList", new { file =[file]});